# How to create a Column expression from collection of column names?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of strings, which represents the names of various columns I want to add together to make another column:

```
val myCols = List("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

I want to convert the list to columns, then add the columns together to make a final column. I've looked for a number of ways to do this, and the closest I can come to the answer is:

```
df.withColumn("myNewCol", myCols.foldLeft(lit(0))(col(_) + col(_)))
```

I get a compile error where it says it is looking for a string, when all I really want is a column. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried it out in `spark-shell` it gave me the error that says exactly what the error is and where.

```
scala> myCols.foldLeft(lit(0))(col(_) + col(_))
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
       myCols.foldLeft(lit(0))(col(_) + col(_))
                                   ^
```

Just think of the first pair that is given to the function of `foldLeft`. It's going to be `lit(0)` of type `Column` and `col1` of type String. There's no `col` function that accepts a `Column`.

Try [reduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/AbstractIterable.html#reduceLeft%5BB%3E:A%5D(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) instead:

```
myCols.map(col).reduce(_ + _)
```

---

From the official documentation of [reduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/AbstractIterable.html#reduceLeft%5BB%3E:A%5D(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B):

> Applies a binary operator to all elements of this collection, going right to left.
>
> the result of inserting op between consecutive elements of this collection, going right to left:
>
> ```
> op(x_1, op(x_2, ..., op(x_{n-1}, x_n)...))
> ```
>
> where x1, ..., xn are the elements of this collection.

Comment: @Salim `reduce` is a simpler `foldLeft` and enough for the case, isn't it?

Comment: @Jacek yes they are equivalent. I am just pointing out the syntax fix which will make the existing code work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add columns dynamically based on the column names on a List. When all columns are numeric the result is a number. The 1st variable on foldLeft is of same type as return. foldLeft would work as much as reduce.

```
    val employees = //a dataframe with 2 numeric columns "salary","exp"
    val initCol = lit(0)
    val cols = Seq("salary","exp")

    val col1 = cols.foldLeft(initCol)((x,y) => x + col(y))

    employees.select(col1).show()
```

Comment: _"Assuming that all columns are numeric."_ Why? What if not?

Comment: when I do col(x) + col(y), x is numeric and y is string then + operation gives NULL. it gives a sum when both are number. I think the @Geoffery wants to add numeric values

Comment: It's true, I wanted to add numeric values, but I wanted to keep the question generic and thus useful for other people who aren't using numerics.